# The getter 'activePageIndex' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: activePageIndex)

Tags: flutter, dart

while creating a liquid swipe with smooth page indicator I am getting an error
the error which I getting is

## NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'activePageIndex' was called on null. Receiver: nullTried calling: activePageIndex)

Please anyone can help me to get rid of this error

My Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:liquid_swipe/liquid_swipe.dart'; 
import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart'; 
void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SwipeHome(),
    );
  }
}
class SwipeHome extends StatefulWidget {
 

  @override
  State<SwipeHome> createState() => _SwipeHomeState();
}

class _SwipeHomeState extends State<SwipeHome> {

  final controller= LiquidController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     body: Stack(
       children :[
        LiquidSwipe(
          liquidController: controller,
        enableSlideIcon: true,
       onPageChangeCallback: (index){
        setState(() {
          
        });
       },
        slideIconWidget: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,color: Colors.white,),
        
        
        pages:[
        BuildPage(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 27, 4, 119),
         urlImage: "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/articles/04HUXgEu0I3mdCOejOjQpNE-5.fit_lim.size_1600x900.v1620748900.jpg",
          title: "Facebook",
           subtitle: "nfvfhgsdcfyfshsiufifuihgiugerbdfyfu"),
            BuildPage(color: Colors.white,
         urlImage: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1636751364472-12bfad09b451?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80",
          title: "Whatsapp",
           subtitle: "nfvfhgsdcfyfshsiufifuihgiugerbdfyfu"),
            BuildPage(color: Colors.orange,
         urlImage: "https://akm-img-a-in.tosshub.com/indiatoday/images/story/202108/Instagram_0.jpg?ZZLGdE1PjohTO.aeUOUEQYBxAWLPgCGT&size=770:433",
          title: "Instagram",
           subtitle: "nfvfhgsdcfyfshsiufifuihgiugerbdfyfu")
       ]),
       Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        left: 16,
        right: 32,
        child: Row(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
       children: [
        TextButton(onPressed: (){
          controller.animateToPage(page: 2);
        }, child: Text("Skip",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15),)),

      AnimatedSmoothIndicator(activeIndex:controller.currentPage,//THIS IS WHERE I AM GETTING ERROR//
       count: 3,
       effect: JumpingDotEffect(),
        onDotClicked: (index){
         controller.animateToPage(page: index);
        },
       ),

        TextButton(onPressed: (){
         final page = controller.currentPage+1;
          controller.animateToPage(page: page>3?0:page,duration: 300);
        }, child: Text("Next",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15),)),
        
      
       ],
       ))
       ]
     )
    );
  }
  Widget BuildPage({required Color color,
  required String urlImage,
  required String title,
  required String subtitle,


  }){
    return Container(
    color: color,
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Image.network(urlImage,fit: BoxFit.cover,
        width: double.infinity,),
        SizedBox(height: 64),
        Center(child: Text(title,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 28,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
        SizedBox(height: 24),
        Container(
          child: Text(subtitle,style:TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20,)),
        )

      ],
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

*Plz anyone can help me to get rid of this error

Comment: I am not sure but I am not able to reproduce your issue.Its working fine for me

Comment: When are you getting this error?

Comment: AnimatedSmoothIndicator(activeIndex:controller.currentPage, this is where i am getting error @Rohit

Comment: yesterday @Rohit

Comment: hmm. I am not sure . I am still not able to reproduce it. I am using exact same code